# git fetch corrupts FETCH_HEAD

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have several git repositories, and when I do `git fetch` in any of them, file `.git/FETCH_HEAD` seems to be updated in this way: its content is taken, converted to NUL ascii characters and then new data from fetch appended. After that, `git merge FETCH_HEAD` failed.

[Corrupted FETCH_HEAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EccHY.png)

The first time after cloning a new repository `git fetch` works ok, maybe because there is no `FETCH_HEAD`.

The same issue applies to any repository I tried, GitHub too.

My colleagues don't have the issue with the same repositories, I don't have it on my another computer.

I might break some git config file before the issue started to appear, but I completedly remove everything related to git I could find (`system`, `global` settings, `%home%/gitconfig`, etc).

I tried: clone repos again, in different folders; remove git and install latest version 2.18; use portable git 2.17.

I didn't try: reinstall windows.

> Win10 x64, git 2.17, 2.18.

Comment: Never seen that. Maybe your git client is loading some wrong DLLs from another installed program, that may happen if you have a funny `PATH`. You can try setting the `PATH` to the simplest possible, deleting your `FETCH_HEAD` and trying again. In my PC it is: `export PATH=/mingw32/bin/; rm .git/FETCH_HEAD; git fetch`

Comment: Changed PATH: echo $PATH
/mingw64/bin/:/bin/ - all the same.

Comment: That's a fascinating failure mode. I wonder if your `git fetch` operation is attempting / directed to append to the `FETCH_HEAD` file (via the `-a` or `--append` flag) and then somehow turning all the existing file data into zero-bytes.

Comment: It seems to do exactly this, but I don't use `-a` option, though I tried it to see if it does any difference (it doesn't).

Comment: 5 years later and I have the same problem. I was using Git for Windows v2.28 or something. It was working for few months perfectly fine. And suddenly this. Upgrade/reinstall to Git for Windows v2.41.0 didn't help.